# Having trouble getting Bitcoal network to accept submitblock

Tags: mining, mining-pools, hash-verification

EDIT: I think this is because it was upcased? I downcased the blob and found another block, now my wallet shows a locked balance!

I am solo mining on a easy coin now to learn how mining works, bitcoal.

I get to the point where I find a valid share and generate the submitblock blob, submit the blob to the bitcoal daemon.   The daemon returns me a status of "OK".  But when I check my wallet, it shows 0 balance and 0 locked.

Here is an example of a bitcoal block I mined. At height 433740.

```
coal block found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
```

Here it is on the block explorer http://democats.org/blockchain/block/?name=bitcoal&hash=433740.

And here is me submitting it to the daemon.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:7701/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"submitblock","params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}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

"{\"id\":\"0\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":{\"status\":\"OK\"}}"
```

Comment: As you seemed to have solved your problem, could you leave it in the answer section to help future users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I was submitting an upper cased hex blob. You must submit it as lowercase.

Comment: I doubt that. What is the evidence for this claim ? If this is a difference from Monero to Bitcoal, then that would be good evidence.